# VLOOKUP comparing dates

Tags: validation-rule

I would like to create a validation rule which check duplication on all `Effective_Date__c` on `Job__c` object. I want to keep them unique.

```
fHCM2__Effective_Date__c ==  VLOOKUP( $ObjectType.fHCM2__Job__c.Fields.fHCM2__Effective_Date__c , $ObjectType.fHCM2__Job__c.Fields.fHCM2__Effective_Date__c, fHCM2__Effective_Date__c)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep a date field as a unique identifier, there is no straight forward way of doing it.

The workaround i had done was

- Create a text field and make that unique.
- Create a workflow to update that text field with the value from the
  date field Make sure the workflow fires every time the record is
  created or edited

I am not sure if we can do this with validation rule. Its not that its not possible but i dont know if we can do it. Maybe other gurus could pitch in on that.